# IllegalComponentStateException in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, java-7

While doing a basing java swing program, I had a weird error that I had only on my computer (I tried on 2 other and it was all fine).

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ModalDialogsTest extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

        private JButton choice;

        ModalDialogsTest(){
                setSize(400,300);
                JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                getContentPane().add(panel);
                panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
            choice = new JButton("My button");
            panel.add(choice);
            choice.addActionListener(this);
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                        simpleStringChoiceDialog();
        }

        private void simpleStringChoiceDialog(){
                Object[] possibilities = {"choice 1", "choice 2", "choice 3"};
                String s = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                                    this, null, null,
                                    JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null,
                                    possibilities, possibilities[0]);
                System.out.println(s);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
                ModalDialogsTest newWindow = new ModalDialogsTest();
                newWindow.setVisible(true);
        }
}
```

The problem is I get an error when I click on the dropdown menu to select a choice. The error is:

```
    java.awt.IllegalComponentStateException: component must be showing on the screen to determine its location
    at java.awt.Component.getLocationOnScreen_NoTreeLock(Component.java:2044)
    at java.awt.Component.getLocationOnScreen(Component.java:2018)
    at sun.lwawt.macosx.CAccessibility$22.call(CAccessibility.java:390)
    at sun.lwawt.macosx.CAccessibility$22.call(CAccessibility.java:388)
    at sun.lwawt.macosx.LWCToolkit$CallableWrapper.run(LWCToolkit.java:527)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:241)
    at sun.lwawt.macosx.LWCToolkit$CPeerEvent.dispatch(LWCToolkit.java:684)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:682)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:680)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:244)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:155)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:182)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:221)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:219)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1077)
    at javax.swing.JOptionPane.showInputDialog(JOptionPane.java:583)
    at ModalDialogsTest.simpleStringChoiceDialog(ModalDialogsTest.java:109)
    at ModalDialogsTest.actionPerformed(ModalDialogsTest.java:70)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:723)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:682)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:680)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:696)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:693)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:244)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:151)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:147)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:139)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97)
    choice 2
```

### As you can see, an error occur but I can still get the result of the function so I don't get what's wrong... Any clue? I'm using Java 7 on MacOS X Mountain Lion.

Ok so here are the results of what you asked me:
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.vm.name")); gave me:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM.
```

System.getProperties().list(System.out); gave me:

```
-- listing properties --
java.runtime.name=Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
sun.boot.library.path=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk...
java.vm.version=23.3-b01
user.country.format=IE
gopherProxySet=false
java.vm.vendor=Oracle Corporation
java.vendor.url=http://java.oracle.com/
path.separator=:
java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
file.encoding.pkg=sun.io
user.country=FR
sun.java.launcher=SUN_STANDARD
sun.os.patch.level=unknown
java.vm.specification.name=Java Virtual Machine Specification
user.dir=/Users/hugo/Documents/workspace/dialogs
java.runtime.version=1.7.0_07-b10
java.awt.graphicsenv=sun.awt.CGraphicsEnvironment
java.endorsed.dirs=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk...
os.arch=x86_64
java.io.tmpdir=/var/folders/2n/q2bb2df90qqb_x38djlwx...
line.separator=

java.vm.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation
os.name=Mac OS X
sun.jnu.encoding=US-ASCII
java.library.path=/Users/hugo/Library/Java/Extensions:/...
java.specification.name=Java Platform API Specification
java.class.version=51.0
sun.management.compiler=HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers
os.version=10.8
http.nonProxyHosts=local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16
user.home=/Users/hugo
user.timezone=
java.awt.printerjob=sun.lwawt.macosx.CPrinterJob
file.encoding=US-ASCII
java.specification.version=1.7
user.name=hugo
java.class.path=/Users/hugo/Documents/workspace/dialo...
java.vm.specification.version=1.7
sun.arch.data.model=64
java.home=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk...
sun.java.command=ModalDialogsTest
java.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation
user.language=fr
user.language.format=en
awt.toolkit=sun.lwawt.macosx.LWCToolkit
java.vm.info=mixed mode
java.version=1.7.0_07
java.ext.dirs=/Users/hugo/Library/Java/Extensions:/...
sun.boot.class.path=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk...
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
file.separator=/
java.vendor.url.bug=http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/
sun.cpu.endian=little
sun.io.unicode.encoding=UnicodeBig
sun.font.fontmanager=sun.font.CFontManager
socksNonProxyHosts=local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16
ftp.nonProxyHosts=local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16
sun.cpu.isalist=
```

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I tried on another mac exactly like mine (except mine has more memory but it doesn't matter) and on a windows 7 computer.

Comment: Please understand that many of us have firewalls that prevent us from clicking on links. Regardless, if you're asking for free advice, you should make it easy as possible for folks to help you, including posting relevant code here on this site with your question. My 2 cents.

Comment: Possible (likely) reason: you don't seem to be updating the UI components from the EDT thread.

Comment: My question though is this: are you making all Swing calls on the Swing event thread, including the creation of your GUI?

Comment: I have run the provided code on Java6 LinuxMint13 with no problem, will install Java7 and feedback shortly

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels yes he is

Comment: @linski if your answer is about making swing calls from the EDT: no he is not. And that is the likeliest reason for the issue.

Comment: @linski: no, he's not. He needs to create a Runnable and create an instance of his class in the run method, and then pass it to `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)`.

Comment: exactly, my bad  i apologize :)

Comment: if you would like to answer for rep ill delete my post

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answers! You're very fast! I'm not sure that I get all your're saying about working in the good thread as I'm a beginner in Java... So, what do I need to change exactly in my code please?

Comment: You're welcome, but you should thank Hovercrafart :) For starters, just write every Swing(GUI) program main method like in the answer. To learn, read and program examples from this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html)

Comment: I was thanking all of you (: ...but it still does not work for some reason... :'(

Comment: Are you sure you have posted the *entire* stacktrace?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same issue with Java 7 on Mac Yosemite. In my case it is caused by a third party tool called "Cinch" that I use for arranging my windows on the desktop. Deactivating the tool let the Exceptions disappear.

Comment: Yes indeed it worked for me too! 
After all those years of having this annoying problem I'm glad it is finally fixed! Thanks so much!

Comment: This is really odd because what could Cinch be doing in the background that would cause the JComboBox to "forget" it's being shown. My best guess might be that it is doing something funny with the memory and it possibly clears a bit that says the Combo Box is not being shown, when indeed it is. But that seems unlikely, so I am not sure.

Comment: Thank you! That solved my issue with my Macbook Pro's matlab. :)

Answer (score 4):

Are you maybe using the (otherwise excellent) window management enhancer [zooom](http://www.coderage-software.com/zooom/index.html)?

I get this error all the time with certain Java GUIs, even with commercial software like Matlab.

Besides cluttering consoles, it never really seemed to disturb any functionality.

Unfortunately I don't have a solution. But maybe knowing this could be the cause is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite as Hovercraft Full Of Eels said:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            ModalDialogsTest newWindow = new ModalDialogsTest();
            newWindow.setVisible(true);
        }
    });

}
```

the exception should no longer appear.

EDIT:

compiled and runned with Oracle Java7 with no problem. It looks like OpenJDK for Mac has some [issues](http://java.net/jira/browse/MACOSX_PORT-337). If I hadn't seen this I'd be convinced that you hadn't posted the entire stacktrace. <strike>*Please verify once again that you have posted the entire stacktrace.* If you have posted the entire stacktrace</strike> then:

1. Are you using OpenJDK or [Oracle Java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7u7-downloads-1836413.html)?
2. The other two computers were also Macs or?

To check what JVM implementation you are using, put this line in your code:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.vm.name"));
```

and post the output. If the output is null put this line:

```
System.getProperties().list(System.out);
```

and post output.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried and it did not change anything... :/ Any other idea?

Comment: well, my Java7 just downloaded, BRB

Comment: In case it may change something, I'm running my code in Eclipse Juno.

Comment: I answered you in a proper answer as it was easier to make it readable. Please see below (:

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea. Make your `panel` variable global and then change the first argument of `showInputDialog` from `this` to `panel`.

```
            String s = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                                panel, null, null,
                                JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null,
                                possibilities, possibilities[0]);
```

EDIT:

I think that these lines

```
at javax.swing.JOptionPane.showInputDialog(JOptionPane.java:583)
at ModalDialogsTest.simpleStringChoiceDialog(ModalDialogsTest.java:109)
```

suggest that the problem is the `parentComponent` argument of `showInputDialog`. Change your code and create a `JFrame` instead of extending it. See also [this](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=19861) and [this](http://www.moparscape.org/smf/index.php?topic=382718.0)

EDIT 2:

I changed your code a bit, run it and if the exception is still there, then I have no clue what else could be the problem....

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ModalDialogsTest implements ActionListener{

    private JButton choice;
    private JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    ModalDialogsTest() {
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        choice = new JButton("My button");
        panel.add(choice);
        choice.addActionListener(this);        
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400,300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        simpleStringChoiceDialog();
    }

    private void simpleStringChoiceDialog() {
        Object[] possibilities = {"choice 1", "choice 2", "choice 3"};
        String s = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                    frame.getContentPane(), null, null,
                    // panel, null, null,                   // <-- or this
                    JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null,
                    possibilities, possibilities[0]);
                    System.out.println(s);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new ModalDialogsTest();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: JFrame is subclass of Component so that should not matter, but try it to be sure.

Comment: @koleror try using `null` instead as an argument

Comment: How can I do to create an Iframe? Sorry I feel a bit newby :/